Translation Invariants of Polynomials
The function $f(k)$ is a (numerical) polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[k]$, and the set
$ S_f = \{ f_d : d \in \mathbb{N} \} $
is a set associated with $ f $, where $f_d(k)=f(k+d)$.
I am interested in finding invariants related to $S_f$, that is, I want to find a map from $\{ S_f \}$ to some set, such as  $\deg(f)$ and the leading coefficient of $ f $.
Note that it is not necessarily a map from $\{ S_f \}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$; it would be great if each given $S_f$ could correspond to an algebraic or geometric structure.
By comparing coefficients, one can directly obtain some invariants modulo the coefficients of higher-order terms, but I am looking for more "interesting" conclusions.

Well, every such set contains a unique polynomial starting with $a_n k^n + a_{n-1}k^{n-1}+\ldots$ with $0 \le a_{n-1} < da_n$, so you can map $S_f$ to this polynomial.

By ${S_f}$ do you mean ${S_f:f\in Q[x]}$? You really want a map from this set, or from the set of polynomials? What is $k$ in the definition of $S_f$?

@YCor, I want a map from this set. In other words, I want a map $\phi$ from $\mathbb Q[k]$ such that $\phi(f) =\phi(f_d)$ for each $d\in \mathbb N$, where $f_d:k\mapsto f(k+d)$.
